# How do you save an **EXCEL** XML file with linq?

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, excel

I'm loading and saving an Excel XML file using XElement using the following blurb:

```
    Dim root As XElement = XElement.Load(inFile)
    'code to change elements goes here 
    root.Save(outFile)
```

The problem is that the Save routine is adding namespace tags as well as who knows what, so that Excel and windows no longer recognizes this as an Excel XML file.  In my example, I'm not even manipulating elements.  I'm just loading and saving the file.  I basically want to use linq to find certain elements in the XML, change those then save the whole file.  Am I making this too hard?

inFile XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Datagrid">
    <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="13" ss:ExpandedRowCount="11" x:FullColumns="1"
     x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
      <Row ss:Index="3" ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <Cell ecProperty="email_address">
          <Data ss:Type="String">email address</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row ss:Index="4" ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <Cell ecProperty="synthesis_mode">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Ideal Mode</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

outFile Results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Datagrid">
    <ss:Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="13" ss:ExpandedRowCount="11" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
      <ss:Row ss:Index="3" ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <ss:Cell ecProperty="email_address">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">email address</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
      </ss:Row>
      <ss:Row ss:Index="4" ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <ss:Cell ecProperty="synthesis_mode">
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Ideal Mode</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
      </ss:Row>
    </ss:Table>
  </ss:Worksheet>
</ss:Workbook>
```

Comment: Seems like a gotcha when the default namespace is also defined in a prefix...

Comment: The problem is <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?> is not being saved.  If I add that in manually, I get the desired results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) instead of `XElement` to preserve the full document.

```
Dim root As XDocument = XDocument.Load(inFile)
'code to change elements goes here 
root.Save(outFile)
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following you.

Comment: that worked!  I'll mark this as correct, but do you know why (or how to prevent the ss: namespace getting added when saving?

Comment: The why is simple: the `XElement` does not store surrounding nodes, but only an element and everything *inside*. The `XDocument` stores the full document including any XML declaration, comment, processing instruction etc. nodes. However, I don't have a solution for the namespace prefix gotcha, it seems to be caused by the fact that the namespace used as default namespace is re-declared with a prefix and it only uses the prefixed one. Removing the prefix however is not possible due to the attributes which require the prefix.